# Integrity Error django with UniqueConstraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following model snippet:

```
class InvoiceReference(TemplateMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    reference_prefix = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=(RegexValidator(regex='^\S+$',
                                  message='reference prefix must not include spaces'),)
    )
    reference_offset = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    reference_suffix = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        validators=(RegexValidator(regex='^\S+$',
                                  message='reference suffix must not include spaces'),)
    )
    reference_separator = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('user', 'reference_prefix', 'reference_suffix', 'reference_separator',), name='unique_reference')
        ]
```

The idea is to have it so that a no single user cannot use the same reference_prefix, reference_separator and reference_suffix together multiple times. (if *different* users use the same combination of reference_prefix, reference_separator and reference_suffix this is ok.)

I am currently using the django-admin model form, where I have excluded the user field and attach a user in save_model:

```
class InvoiceReferenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = InvoiceReference
    exclude = ('user',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.pk:
            obj.user = request.user
        super().save_model(request=request, obj=obj, form=form, change=change)
```

however, this results in an 'Integrity Error' when I try to save the model.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: invoice_invoice.user_id, invoice_invoice.reference_prefix, invoice_invoice.reference_suffix, invoice_invoice.reference_separator

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 606, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1645, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1529, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1572, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/Users/leonhughes/dev/django/invoiceweb/invoice/admin.py", line 42, in save_model
    super().save_model(request=request, obj=obj, form=form, change=change)
  File "django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1088, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1375, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: invoice_invoice.user_id, invoice_invoice.reference_prefix, invoice_invoice.reference_suffix, invoice_invoice.reference_separator
```

I have seen this in the django documentation

> In general constraints are not checked during full_clean(), and do not
> raise ValidationErrors. Rather you’ll get a database integrity error
> on save(). UniqueConstraints without a condition (i.e. non-partial
> unique constraints) are different in this regard, in that they
> leverage the existing validate_unique() logic, and thus enable
> two-stage validation. In addition to IntegrityError on save(),
> ValidationError is also raised during model validation when the
> UniqueConstraint is violated.

As I have no conditions set shouldn't a ValidationError be raised first?

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: You already added a record for this `('user', 'reference_prefix', 'reference_suffix', 'reference_separator')` combination.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you explain more?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I understand, but how do I show it as a validation error in the form? If I remove the ‘user’ from the UniqueConstraint I get a form validation error. However, with ‘user’ I get an integrity error.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve a similar result as yours would be to make `user` a hidden field in your admin form and then override [`ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data) to pass the current user as the value for this hidden input.

This would mean that the user would be included in unique validation checks as the field would not be excluded from the form. When editing an existing object initial data is ignored so you shouldn't override any existing user relation

```
class InvoiceReferenceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceReference
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput}


class InvoiceReferenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = InvoiceReference
    form = InvoiceReferenceAdminForm

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'user': request.user}
```

Comment: I have seen a similar answer to this before. I would prefer not to go down this route with a custom form so that this validation can be kept in one place for use elsewhere in the system (eventually outside of django admin)

Comment: This method does not interfere with the validation, it's just a method for hiding a field